# Volume Write Permissions

Tags: kubernetes, tekton, tekton-pipelines

How can I give the non-root user full access to the mounted volume path in Kubernetes (pod)?

I'm using a volume on the host (/workspace/projects path) and writing to the directory as below.

```
volumeMounts:
-name: workspace
 mountPath: /workspace/projects
```

Since, I'm copying the git repository content to the **/projects** directory, the git sets the permission to 755 by default. I want to set the permission to 775 as unable to write to the **/project** directory.

Could you please let me know what is the best way to do this? I saw **InitContainers** and not sure whether there is any better solution.Appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks! Since, this should work for any user, how can I pass the uid of the logged in /current user who runs the pod yaml ? I believe I  can try $uid or something. Please let me know if there is any better solution. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

When you have to run process inside container as non-root user and you mount a volume to pod. But the volume have `root:root` permission.

To give access to specific user initContainer is one way, like following

```
initContainers:
- name: volume-mount-permission
  image: busybox
  command: ["sh", "-c", "chmod 775 /workspace/projects && chown -R <user> /workspace/projects"]
  volumeMounts:
  -name: workspace
   mountPath: /workspace/projects
```

You can also use [security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/). Create user and group, add user to the group in Dockerfile and set following in spec

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: <UID>
    runAsGroup: <GID>
    fsGroup: <GID>
```